# Getting an Error while using EXCEPT clause

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Attached above is the  question I am trying to solve. As a start, I wanted to try using the EXCEPT clause in SQL, and get all the values that are not present in the Orders table. This is what I am trying: (Ignore the column names and stuff for now, I just want to test the EXCEPT logic)

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Customers
EXCEPT
SELECT O.CustomerId as Id, C.Name AS Name FROM Customers C , Orders O
WHERE C.Id = O.CustomerId
```

However, I get this error on LeetCode which I am not sure about:

```
Line 3: SyntaxError: near 'SELECT O.CustomerID as Id, C.Name AS Name FROM Customers C , Orders O WHERE C.Id'
```

The expected output I want out of the query I wrote is:

```
Id    Name
2     Henry
4     Max
```

EDIT: This is a problem on LeetCode, and after looking which version it uses I found it is mysql-server 5.7.21

Comment: dangling `)` ... And please *always* disclose the RDBMS and version you are working with.

Comment: Thanks, but the dangling ) doesnt solve it either. I am not sure which RDBMS and version leetcode uses- I haven't tried running the same locally yet.

Comment: It's *your* responsibility to find that out - to make the question useful to others. Error messages from unknown source aren't mighty useful.

Comment: Much better. One more thing: we very much prefer data as *text*, not as image.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your dbms is mysql. Mysql didn't support `EXCEPT`

Another way you can try to use `NOT IN` will be easier than `EXCEPT`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE  Customers(
   id int,
   Name varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (1,'Joe');
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (2,'Henry');
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (3,'Sam');
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (4,'Max');

CREATE TABLE  Orders(
   id int,
   CustomerId int
);

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (2,1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Customers
WHERE Id NOT IN (
   SELECT O.CustomerID
   FROM Orders O 
);

| Id  | Name  |
| --- | ----- |
| 2   | Henry |
| 4   | Max   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hedPv8dPLCUY2AnpeCDHCy/0)

If your dbms support `EXCEPT`,I would use `JOIN` instead of `,` to connect two tables because `JOIN` 
have a clearer semantic meaning to connect two tables.

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Customers
EXCEPT
SELECT O.CustomerID as Id, C.Name AS Name
FROM Customers C JOIN Orders O ON C.Id = O.CustomerID
```

Comment: How is this join different from what I do?

EDIT: This gives the same error, still.

Comment: The question asked for returning tuples that are not contained in some table, so my first intuition was to use EXCEPT.

Comment: @TheBolt What's your dbms?

Comment: @TheBolt My first query work is sqlfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hedPv8dPLCUY2AnpeCDHCy/1 , which is postgresql

Comment: @TheBolt I edit my answer add more detail about `How is this join different from what I do`

Comment: @D-Shih I am not sure- this is a problem on LeetCode. Maybe it has to do something with LeetCode only then. I did write a solution with NOT IN and that works, but cannot figure out why a simple EXCEPT clause isnt returning what I expect it would.

Comment: @TheBolt Mysql didn't support `EXCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `EXCEPT`, make that `EXCEPT ALL`:

```
SELECT Id FROM Customers
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders;
```

But I'd rather use `LEFT JOIN / .. IS NULL`:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM   Customers C
LEFT   JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
WHERE  O.CustomerId IS NULL;
```

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)